# Upload image in angular, Required request part '' is not present

Tags: mysql, angular, spring, file

I can't find any solution for the Upload image in angular .. Note: the Spring back-end works.

> Required request part 'condidat' is not present

---

- Controller

```
@PutMapping(
          path="/{id}",
          consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.ALL_VALUE},
          produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.ALL_VALUE}
  )
  public ResponseEntity<CondidatResponse> updateCondidat(
          @PathVariable String id , @RequestPart(value = "condidat") CondidatRequest condidatRequest,
          @RequestPart(value = "photo", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
```

---

- [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO5Nm.png)

---

- Service

```
updateC(id: string, photo: FormData){
 return this.http.put(${environment.baseUrl}/condidat/ + id,  photo);
 }
```

---

- Ts

```
updateCond() {
   this.con.userId = this.id;
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('photo', this.photo);
   this.con.photo = this.photo.name;
   console.log(this.con);
   formData.append('condidat', JSON.stringify(this.con));
   this.sign.updateC(this.id, formData)
     .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.router.navigate(['/profil']);
     });
   this.toastr.warning('Data update successfully !!', 'UPDATE', {
     timeOut: 3000,
     positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left'
   });
 }
 onSelectFile(event: any) {
   if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
     this.photo = event.target.files[0];
     this.message = this.photo;
     console.log(this.message);
   }
 }
```

---

- html

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" />
```

....

---

---

- Problem

> message: "Required request part 'condidat' is not present"

---

Comment: could you try to invert the order of `.append`ing  ifields to formData?

Comment: yes, always the same problem

Comment: try to check the network tab and see what is being sent

Comment: eror 500 timestamp: "2021-04-13T15:49:07.936+0000", message: "Required request part 'condidat' is not present"}
message: "Required request part 'condidat' is not present"
timestamp: "2021-04-13T15:49:07.936+0000"

Comment: this is the response body. you should check the request one. it should be under Headers tab in the request description

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundaryH7BPpH36VpfQMf9R
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="test api.png"
Content-Type: image/pn
------WebKitFormBoundaryH7BPpH36VpfQMf9R
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="condidat"
{"userId":"NNeCyrE8B5CDLV8yI0SKt34b3VJSDxGL","email":"jarray@gmail.com","admin":1,"enabled":null,"firstName":null,"phone":null,"lastName":null,"photo":"test api.png","gender":null,"date_birthday":null,"nationality":null}